# Pyglet Importerror : cannot import name key

Tags: python, python-2.7, window, macos-carbon, pyglet

So I'm trying to learn how to use pyglet, and have zero experience using any GLs or 3D-programs. I'm trying to open a window using pyglet and keep getting this error. I've heard that pyglet needs to switch up to 32 bit before it can work on snow leopard but I'm not quite sure if that is the exact problem.

Some System Info: Using Python 2.7, Enthought Canopy Interpreter, Terminal Python is Original Python 2.7 not Enthought Distribution. Mac OS 10.6.8 Snow Leopard. Pyglet is version that comes with latest Enthought Canopy free version.

Here is the error:

```
import pyglet
    ...: 
    ...: win = pyglet.window.Window()
    ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-c91a7ca30a2f> in <module>()
      1 import pyglet
      2 
----> 3 win = pyglet.window.Window()
      4 

/Users/lievbirman/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet  /__init__.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
    304 
    305             import_name = 'pyglet.%s' % self._module_name
--> 306             __import__(import_name)
    307             module = sys.modules[import_name]
    308             object.__setattr__(self, '_module', module)

/Users/lievbirman/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py in <module>()
   1667     # Try to determine which platform to use.
   1668     if sys.platform == 'darwin':
-> 1669         from pyglet.window.carbon import CarbonPlatform, CarbonWindow
   1670         _platform = CarbonPlatform()
   1671         Window = CarbonWindow

/Users/lievbirman/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/carbon/__init__.py in <module>()
     47 from pyglet.window import WindowException, Platform, Display, Screen,      48     BaseWindow, MouseCursor, DefaultMouseCursor, _PlatformEventHandler
---> 49 from pyglet.window import key
     50 from pyglet.window import mouse
     51 from pyglet.window import event

ImportError: cannot import name key
```

My greatest thanks in advance to anyone that can shine some light on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on another thread:
[Installing Pyglet in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311119/installing-pyglet-in-mac?rq=1)

Run 32-bit Python by doing this in the terminal:

defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and I just uninstalled pyglet first and then install it again using:

> > pip install hg+https://pyglet.googlecode.com/hg/

Before reinstalling it make sure you have mercurial installed as well