# Installing Pyglet in mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pyglet, pyobjc

I have followed [this link](http://twistedpairdevelopment.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/installing-pyglet-in-mac-os-x/) in order to install pyglet in mac, because it is the only resource I have found that solves the "wrong architecture" problem. However, when I execute the last commmand `pip install pyobjc==2.2`, it gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_install_lib'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/Gb/Gbm1htNCGKeECJJNr2vUpk+++TQ/-Tmp-/pip_build_nueye/pyobjc-core/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/Gb/Gbm1htNCGKeECJJNr2vUpk+++TQ/-Tmp-/pip-6kYwdv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/Gb/Gbm1htNCGKeECJJNr2vUpk+++TQ/-Tmp-/pip_build_nueye/pyobjc-core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 68: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried to execute [the helloworld example from the pyglet programing guide](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/hello_world.html) anyway, but when I execute `pyglet.app.run()`, the pyglet window freezes and does not display anything.

Do you have any idea why this is happening? Is there another way to install pyglet in mac?

Comment: The helloworld link is HTTP 404 now. Perhaps this is the new link: https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the point of your pyobjc install ?

The issue with Pyglet on osX is 64-bit architecture, so just try this to force python to go 32bit by typing this in your console:

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
```

Comment: I am installing pyobjc because the link where the pyglet installation is explainded says so. 
I'll try to use the 32bit python as soon as I can. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I installed **pyglet** this way.
after downloading **pyglet**, and after i opened Terminal on my mac (with my name displayed ending with $) 
I typed

```
cd /usr/local/bin
```

then I typed `ls` (list command) which showed me I had `pip3` and `pip3.6` as well as `python3.6` (and other files)
so then I typed in this

```
python3.6 -m pip install pyglet
```

and pyglet installed and showed
Collecting pyglet

```
  Downloading pyglet-1.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (964kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 972kB 1.2MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pyglet
Successfully installed pyglet-1.2.4
```